# What would be an appropriate external drive for RaspberryPi backups?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, backup

I am running my Raspberry 24/7 and would like to use a backup-script on a daily basis via a cronjob. That script puts certain contents together in an archive and should then store the archive somewhere.
Can I just use a simple 8GB USB-Stick or is it better to use a SSD for example or a cloud based solution to push the archive, have it online?

Comment: Define better? Faster, Cost, etc.

Comment: I am already owning a SSD and a USB-Stick, so cost should be zero, concerning speed, there are no specific requirements. It is just one RaspberryPi Model 3 Model B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can use a simple 8GB USB-Stick. That's what I do. I'm guessing you already know how to set this up, but to make this a more complete answer, here's an outline. If you have any questions, suggest you edit your question & leave a comment to my answer.

1. Format your USB drive as `ext4`, then make an entry in `/etc/fstab`. Here's an example:

```
LABEL=SANDISK8GB /home/pi/mntBackupDrv ext4 rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

2. Decide what files & folders you want to back up, then create a `bash` script that uses `rsync` to perform the backup. Here's an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -av -F --delete /home/pi/ /home/pi/mntBackupDrv/rpi3b_backup/home/ >> /home/pi/mntBackupDrv/rpi3b_backup/home/rsync_home_backup.txt && \
/bin/echo -e "\nrsync completed: $(date)\n" >> /home/pi/mntBackupDrv/rpi3b_backup/home/rsync_home_backup.txt
```

The script is fairly simple. `/home/pi` is the source, my USB thumb drive is the destination. The activity is logged to a file that's also on the USB drive along with a time stamp.

Read `man rsync` for an explanation of the options; the `-F` simply excludes some files & folders defined in files named `.rsync-filter`.

If you want this stored an archive (tar), and maybe compressed, you could add that to the script - or use it instead of `rsync`.

You should run this script manually to make sure it does what you want it to do before you schedule it with `cron`. Also consider the use of the `--dry-run` option in `rsync` to verify that.

3. Schedule your script to run using `crontab -e`. You could do something like this to backup your `/home/pi` folder:

```
#----------- BACKUP `/home/pi` WITH `rsync` AT ./mntBackupDrv -----------
#
# NOTE: See root's crontab for the backup of /etc
#
55 1 * * * crontab -l > /home/pi/crontab_listing_home.txt
0 2 * * * /home/pi/bkup_pihome.sh
```

Notes re `crontab`:

- This runs two jobs:

  - at 01:55 each day, contents of the `crontab` are output to a file (this backs up my `crontab`)
  - at 02:00 each day, the script `/home/pi/bkup_pihome.sh` is run (see above for listing).
- No `sudo` required for backing up `/home/pi`
- I also backup a few files in /etc - anything I might have changed extensively or frequently. That's not very many files, btw. That requires `sudo`; I do that with `root's crontab`; i.e. `sudo crontab -e`, and a separate script.

---

#### Addendum:

I'd like to include this excellent reference for [Using rsync and cron to automate incremental backups](https://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/02/using-rsync-and-cron-to-automate-incremental-backups.html). There are several ideas relevant to a *backup strategy* in this post worth consideration.

Comment: Thank you so far.
For formatting I used 
https://tecadmin.net/format-usb-in-linux/

\n
What is the effect for the usb drive of the entry in /etc/fstab?

Comment: Concerning scheduling with a cronjob and the backup-script I got everything together, though I had to use the crontab of root ```sudo su -``` + ```crontab -e``` since I want to backup folders in /etc as well.
Did not use rsync just tar the content together.

Comment: One point - if you use ext4 for the format, you are basically forcing yourself to use Linux or extra drivers to read the USB stick.  Formatting the stick as ExFAT allows Macs and PCs to read your backup data if you need to.  The addition of ExFat on the Pi is documented all over (e.g. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-exfat/) also think about how you remove the backup - you need to make sure the data is written to the USB stick before pulling it - a backup in the same physical location is not a solid idea :-)

Comment: @Andyroo: True, but for me, `ext4` is the way to go. Storing backups on `ExFAT` seems a bit like keeping my money under the mattress :)  But all kidding aside - yeah - if cross-platform access to your backups is an important consideration, then exFAT might fit the bill. And yes - always `umount` a mounted drive before pulling it from a running system.

Comment: @Marius: Entry in `/etc/fstab` only means that when you "plug in" that particular USB drive, it is mounted by the system automatically. The alternative is to manually mount the drive before you use it.

Comment: @Marius: If doing all your backups under root's `crontab` works for you, that's fine. I don't use `tar`, but have you checked ownership of the files in your archive after you've "un-tar'd" them?

Comment: @Seamus fare point, got a lot of 'cannot change ownership ...' but found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1435437/how-to-get-around-this-error-when-untarring-an-archive-tar-cannot-change-owner) >>>

```sudo tar -C my_dir/ -zxvf archive.tgz --no-same-owner```

Comment: @quizmaster987: Happy to hear that. ICYI, I've made a small edit to my answer - see the **Addendum** in the answer above.

Comment: @Seamus I looked it up, it seems to be way more sophisticated, will try that, thank you

Answer (score -1):

A NAS. or SSD. But if you your ability to configure it's your own personal cloud and can hold a lot of storage. I have thought about this for years and finally bought one. It's a learning and I riding that curve hard but I think it's worth the time energy, efficiency, and if it matters to you a lot protection. I explained it to my parents as a way to backup their computer just like onedrive wihout that added costs. But you now have onedrive, google drive (to an extent), Icloud (if you hvae an iphone) consolidated in one location. My phone tends to fill up quickly as well as my computer. I download apps and take photos and videos. Next thing you know you have to reinvent the wheel. With this my hope is you set it up accordingly, learn more about computers, and save money and time during those new computer trasnitions. I had a disaster last year. The back took 18 hours and it didn't fully work. Thats when I said NAS is the answer